# Why does box-shadow look different than filter: drop-shadow

Tags: html, css, browser

I've always been using CSS box-shadows since, but now I have an image with rounded corners and wanted to give it a rounded shadow. So I tried using filter: drop-shadow, but unfortunately it looks different from box-shadow. In my opinion, they should look the same, am I doing something wrong?

```css
td {
  padding: .5em 3em;
}
.box-shadow img {
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.drop-shadow img {
   filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>box shadow</th><th>drop shadow</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="box-shadow">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td class="drop-shadow">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is the appearance of these shadows defined in any spec, or do browsers just what they think they should do? Why do those look different?

Chrome/OS X:
[image]

Firefox/OS X:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is a bug. The [W3C specification for CSS filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#funcdef-drop-shadow) states that "values are interpreted as for box-shadow [CSS3BG]." Therefore, similar results should be expected from the two properties.

I achieved a similar issue, as seen here:

```css
#box1, #box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#box1 { /* Using drop shadow, should appear identical to box shadow */
  left: 10px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black)
}

#box2 {
  left: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

This will display incorrectly in Chrome and Firefox like this:

[image: Chrome fail]

However, it will display correctly in Safari like this:

[image: Safari ok]

If I decrease the shadow blur radius in Chrome by a factor of two, I get the expected result:

[image: Chrome adjusted]

I have filed a bug report for [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677689) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1326570).

### UPDATE: January 12, 2017

It turns out it wasn't a bug, but an issue with the specification.

> For a box shadow the blur value is generated by applying to the shadow a Gaussian blur with a standard deviation equal to half the blur radius. - [Robert Longson](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1326570)

A specification issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/102).

Answer (score 2):

they are not the same . they achieve different things.

in the case of `filter:drop-shadow`some browsers do  not support the `spread` value as the `box-shadow` does. that's why they look different.
it also doesn't support `inset`

but as an advantage with **`filter:drop-shadow`** you can generate shadow around irregular shapes or images, whereas **`box-shadows`** generates a rectangular shadow.

see example below :

```css
.boxShadow,.dropShadow {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;

   background:green;
   position:relative;
   float:left;margin:20px;
  
}
.boxShadow {
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
.dropShadow {
 -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);

}
.boxShadow:before,.dropShadow:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  right:0;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxShadow">

</div>
<div class="dropShadow">

</div>
```

as you can see , with `drop-shadow` the `pseudo-element` also has a shadow around it, whereas with `box-shadow` it does not.

see more info here > [Comparison drop-shadow vs box-shadow](http://thenewcode.com/598/box-shadow-property-vs-drop-shadow-filter-a-complete-comparison) or here > [Filter CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

hope it helps

Comment: `box-shadow` does not necessarily generate a rectangular shadow. It can have rounded corners.

Comment: I know that. My question was not about the outline of the shadow, but why the spread etc looks different if the outline/shape is the same. See my screenshots. In other words, why is the top of those two different: http://i.imgur.com/ohaqr3R.png

Answer (score 1):

This most likely explains the rendering differences you are seeing.

> [The big advantage of the drop-shadow filter is that it acknowledges the outline and transparency of an element.](http://bricss.net/post/33158273857/box-shadow-vs-filter-drop-shadow)

Also note the browser support of CSS Drop shadow vs Filter.

- [Can I use `box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)
- [Can I use `filter`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

Comment: I know these two things. But when my shape is an opaque rectangle, why is the shadow different?

Comment: I would make the assumption that this is down to different rendering types.

_This function is similar to the more established box-shadow property; the difference is that with filters, some browsers provide hardware acceleration for better performance._

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()_2)