# When applied to text what is the difference between filter: drop-shadow and text-shadow?

Tags: css

It seems that when `filter: drop-shadow` is applied to text it does almost the same thing as `text-shadow`, however I noticed that if I supply the same values it looks slightly different, `text-shadow` appears to make more clearly defined shadows. Why is it different, and when creating shadows for text which one should be used?

Comment: Maybe some helpful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575894/why-does-box-shadow-look-different-than-filter-drop-shadow

Comment: both are two different function using different algorithm. it's a coincidence that they produce *similar* result for some particular cases but they are never meant to be the same at all